Generic component with mixed datatypes
I created a list component which can handle multiple datatypes.

options can be either a array of objects or an array of any other type.
if options contains objects, there has to be the attribute optionValue.

optionValue is a key of the object in options.


emptyValue will be returned if nothing is selected. The default value for emptyValue is undefined.
value can be

emptyValue or
if options are objects, it is the type of the attribute specified by optionValue
else type of option item



But I cannot figure out how to define the types for value and onChange.
My actual interface looks like this:
interface ListProps<O, V extends keyof O, E>{
  options: O[],
  optionValue?: O extends Record<string, any> ? V : never,
  emptyValue?: E,
  value: (O extends Record<string, any> ? O[V] : O) | E ,
  onChange: (value: (O extends Record<string, any> ? O[V] : O) | E) => void
}

My problem is that E is not infered correct. E should be undefined if emptyValue is not given or the type of emptyValue.
In the following code the value argument in onChange is typed as string, but it should be string | undefined  :
let options = [{id: "x", value: 1}];
let simple = ["1","2","3"];
return <GenericComponent options={options} optionValue="value" emptyValue={undefined} value={9} onChange={(value) => value} />

And another question: Can this interface be better. This is my first attempt with generic components.
